# How to bind a trigger to an Azure Datafactory Pipeline via Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-cli

I'm trying to automatize the creation of azure datafactory pipelines with a script.
I'm able to create the pipeline and the trigger with `az datafactory pipeline create` and `az datafactory trigger create`.

The problem is that I was not able to find a way to bind those two in the AZ CLI documentation, so I don't have to manually add the trigger to the pipeline.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You won't be able to create both using a single command at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently going through the doc [az datafactory trigger create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/datafactory/trigger?view=azure-cli-latest#az_datafactory_trigger_create)

`az datafactory trigger create` command, has **properties**, within which you have **pipelineReference**  where **referenceName** should be assigned the **Pipeline name** that you want to associate this trigger with.

```
az datafactory trigger create --factory-name
                              --name
                              --properties
                              --resource-group
                              [--if-match]
```

`--properties` Expects values: json-string/json-file/@json-file. Personally I suggest you upload a **json** file with properties values to CLI and then reference it using `@file-name.json`

### Example:

Creating a trigger `exampleTrigger` for pipeline `TriggeredPipeline`

**Upload your json file with properties.** *(referenceName = pipeline name you want to add this trigger to)*

```
{
    "type": "ScheduleTrigger",
    "pipelines": [
        {
            "parameters": {
                "OutputBlobNameList": [
                    "exampleoutput.csv"
                ]
            },
            "pipelineReference": {
                "type": "PipelineReference",
                "referenceName": "TriggeredPipeline"
            }
        }
    ],
    "typeProperties": {
        "recurrence": {
            "endTime": "2022-06-16T00:55:13.8441801Z",
            "frequency": "Minute",
            "interval": 4,
            "startTime": "2022-06-16T00:39:13.8441801Z",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Reference uploaded properties file in command**: *(--properties "`@<uploaded-properties-file-name>`.json")*

..

```
az datafactory trigger create --factory-name "testadf" --resource-group "your-resource-group-name" --properties "@properties.json" --name "exampleTrigger"
```

**Verify from ADF Studio:**

[image]

You can use `az datafactory trigger update` with Optional Parameters **--add** and **--set** specifying a properties file , path and value for updating an existing trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I couldn't find the expected schema for the --properties parameter in the documentation. Your answer seems to solve the one trigger per pipeline problem. I assume I can just add entries to the "pipelines" attribute to bind the same trigger to multiple pipelines, right? Thanks again!

Comment: Glad this helps, yes that is correct.

Comment: Hey Karthik, could you elaborate a bit on the --set parameter? I was able to update description of the trigger through  --set properties.description="Test description" but not something like weekdays using --set properties.typeProperties.recurrence.schedule.weekDays=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"]. I think it is expecting the value in different format as I get - argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable